# Alternatives to Google Static Maps when the URL gets too big

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

My end goal is view and print a document (eg, PDF) with business-specific info on it along with a map. The map must have

1. The aerial imagery background
2. The features from a KML file.

Google Static Maps works perfectly for this until the KML gets too complex to fit in the URL. I've already shrunk the URL by reducing long/lat precision and encoding the polylines.

Ideas:

1. I could get the aerial imagery from Google Static Maps, then programmatically draw my KML features onto it, but I'm not sure if that's allowed in the Google Maps Terms of Use.
2. Are there other ways to coerce static maps to give me what I want?
3. Does Google have a different mapping service that could ultimately convert a KML into an image with the aerial image background?
4. Any non-Google services that might help?

Comment: Could try something like Google Url Shortener if the URLs aren't dynamic: http://goo.gl/

Comment: Hi @ChrisCasad - thanks for giving this some thought. I thought that might work, too, but I believe URL shorteners simply do HTTP redirects to the original URL, so the google map servers still only see a too-long URL.